# Android: ExoPlayer direct feed raw mp4 (h264) fragments

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm investigating Android's possibilities for displaying H264 video in an application.

The video stream is inside an mp4 container, and available as byte array in chunk-by-chunk fashion.

(I can also use the [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html), but I don't want to mess with timings.)

I'm looking into ExoPlayer now but I'm a little confused on how can I feed mp4 fragments into it:

There are [MediaSources](https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html):

- DashMediaSource for DASH.
- SsMediaSource for SmoothStreaming.
- HlsMediaSource for HLS.
- ProgressiveMediaSource for regular media files.

But I really want to know:

1. if ExoPlayer is able to handle media (fragmented mp4) from memory (byte array, inputstream or similar)?
2. if yes, which media source is the best way to go?

### Update

I was following @Biscuit's [link](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4212).

I implemented my own DataSource:

```
public class MediaDispatcher implements DataSource {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "MediaDispatcher";
    private DataSpec mDataSpec;
    private String mBuffer;

    @Override
    public void addTransferListener(TransferListener transferListener) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "addTransferListener");
    }

    @Override
    public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) throws IOException {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "open");

        mDataSpec = dataSpec;
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "read, readLength=" + readLength);

        if (0 == readLength) return 0;

        if (readLength > mBuffer.length()) buffer = mBuffer.getBytes();

        return mBuffer.length();
    }

    public void write(String buffer) throws InterruptedException {
        //My service calls this
        mBuffer = buffer;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri getUri() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getUri");
        return Uri.EMPTY;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "close");
    }
}
```

And I'm initializing it like below:

```
DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
    @Override
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return new MediaDispatcher();
    }
};

MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(mMediaDispatcher.getUri(),
            factory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);

mplayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
myVideoLayout.setPlayer(mplayer)
mplayer.prepare(mediaSource);
```

**But my problem is that ExoPlayer wants to read only 1 byte at a time!**

Log:

```
getUri
addTransferListener
open
getUri
getUri
read, readLength=4
read, readLength=1
read, readLength=1
read, readLength=1
read, readLength=1
... (same line repeats)
close
```

<s>Also, `ExtractorMediaSource` is deprecated so I have no idea how to proceed.</s>

I have updated the init part:

```
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(Uri.EMPTY);
```

But ExoPlayer still wants to read only 1 byte at a time.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no easy way to do this but you still can with [ByteArrayDataSource](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/ByteArrayDataSource.html) or [DataSourceInputStream](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DataSourceInputStream.html). You can also look at their issue on github someone made a [custom inputStream](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4212) that might be useful to you.
2. To play MP4 file you need `ProgressiveMediaSource`

Comment: I made an update to my post, please take a look, I'm not able to proceed

Comment: Your usecase seems to be very specific, you might wanna open an issue on their github, they are answering quite quickly.